# How to bypass router VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

**tl;dr:** How do I make my router send traffic through a VPN by default, but allow exceptions when explicitly configured?

I like to use a VPN for my everyday browsing. But I have to configure every computer on my home network with the VPN settings, which is tedious. It seems easier to simply make the router connect to the VPN, and then all the clients will automatically go through it.

The problem is that every once in a while I run into a site the blocks the VPN exit, probably as a security theater. Sometimes these are sites like a bank or a merchant, and simply not using the site is not an option. I must temporarily disable the VPN to access the site.

On my computer, disabling the VPN temporarily is easy. But having to go into the router's admin UI every time just to change the VPN seems tedious. Is it possible to have the router somehow provide a VPN-less path for certain connections without me actually turning off the VPN?

For example, maybe I could host a proxy server such that the server goes outside the VPN, and whenever I need to access a site that bans my VPN, I simply switch my computer to the proxy server. Of course, I still need a way to have the router send connections through the VPN by default, unless they're coming from the proxy server.

The router is running OpenWRT. I also have a Linux server on the same network (and connects to Internet through the router) that I can use for running more elaborate services.

Comment: You can set up source-based routing on the router by having ip rule that looks up alternate route table for certain source IP.

Comment: A simpler option (but not as good as source routing) would be to add more specific routes to the sites that don't like the VPN IP to go straight our your connection. (ie put in /32 or even /24 routes directly out the router covering the IP addresses you don't want to go through a VPN)